# How to do pagination within relation laravel query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

```
   $users = User::whereHas('role', function ($q) {
                $q->where('role_id', 3);
            })
            ->with(['property_managements.new_notifications.type'])
            ->with(['property_managements.new_notifications' => function ($q){
                $q->orderBy('notification_date', 'desc');
            }])
            ->with(['property_managements' => function ($q) {
                $q->whereHas('new_notifications');
            }])
            ->whereHas('property_managements.new_notifications')
            ->get();

I need to paginate the entire data based on "new_notifications" relation data 
That means i want to get users data with paginated based on new_notification relation not based on whole pagination
```

I have tried pagination along with relation but it did not work. It resulted whole users data.

```
 
            ->with(['property_managements.new_notifications' => function ($q){
                $q->orderBy('notification_date', 'desc')
                  ->paginate(10);
            }])
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you want your data to be sorted in New Notifications Order and then paginated?
Like if you want 10 records per page, the first page should have latest Notification Date and so on?

Comment: @HesanNaveed yes

Comment: I have answered to your question below. Kindly check if it is correct then mark it as accepted so that it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users data paginated based on New Notifications Date. Then you can do this

```
$users = User::whereHas('role', function ($q) {
                $q->where('role_id', 3);
            })
            ->with(['property_managements.new_notifications.type'])
            ->with(['property_managements.new_notifications' => function ($q){
                $q->orderBy('notification_date', 'desc');
            }])
            ->with(['property_managements' => function ($q) {
                $q->whereHas('new_notifications');
            }])
            ->whereHas('property_managements.new_notifications')
            ->orderByDesc(
              // Considering NewNotification is Model Name and new_notifications is table name
               NewNotification::select('notification_date') 
                  ->whereColumn('new_notifications.user_id','users.id')
                  ->take(1)
            )
            ->get();
```

You can also get this using Raw Query which would be like:

```
$usersQuery->orderByRaw('(SELECT notification_date FROM new_notifications WHERE new_notifications.id = users.id)')->paginate(10);
```